# What is the difference between Source, Layer and Tileset in MapBox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-api-tilequery

I'm currently going over a piece of code which uses MapBox GL JS and has an addSource() function which looks like this

```
this.mapAdapter.map.addSource(`${this.asset.uuid}-data`, {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: this.getMapboxGeometry(),
      })
```

And another addLayer() function which looks like this

```
this.mapAdapter.map.addLayer({
        id: `${this.asset.uuid}-polygon`,
        type: 'fill',
        source: `${this.asset.uuid}-data`,
        filter: ['==', '$type', 'Polygon'],
        }
```

I want to know what the difference between source and layer is. I can't seem to find a proper clear definition fo it.

The code for feature collection is as follows

```
 type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
      ...}
```

Are layers related to the feature collection in some way?

Are tilesets another name for sources or are they entirely different?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I want to know what the difference between source and layer is. I can't seem to find a proper clear definition fo it.

I had a super similar struggle in trying to understand the differences between sources, layers, datesets, tilesets, styles, etc when I started to learn Mapbox. It is fantastic how much Mapbox offers and how many docs they have, but it is easy to get lost in the noise.

I think of a **sources** as a mini data store for my map and **layers** as the visual representation of a source. Adding the source tells Mapbox that "hey, this is a data store that contains or more layers that could get added to the map". When you add a layer to a map, you then point it at the source and tell Mapbox how to represent the source on the map.

Once you add a source to a map, you can create any number of layers using it. For instance, if I added a source that contained city parks, I could create the following three layers from that single source.

- a `fill` layer that represents the park boundaries as shaded polygons
- a `line` layer that represents the boundaries as an outline
- a `symbol` layer that displays the park names as text labels

I wrote a Mapbox and React Deep Dives series that covers this in more depth. Here are some posts that are super relevant to your questions.

- [A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js)
- [Tilesets & Datasets: Managing Data in Mapbox Studio](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/tilesets-and-datasets-managing-data-in-mapbox-studio)
- [The Mapbox Developer's Handbook](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook)

Answer (score 3):

Sources and layers are defined in the Mapbox-GL Style Spec: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/

In short: sources define where the data comes from, layers define how sources are displayed.

> Are layers related to the feature collection in some way?

Not really.

> Are tilesets another name for sources or are they entirely different?

Vector tilesets are one type of source. GeoJSON sources (like what you are using here) are another.

Comment: Is the source used to render maps?

Comment: Do layers create annotations on the map sources?

Comment: I'd really recommend reading all the way through the Mapbox-GL-JS documentation - the API and Style Spec pages.

Comment: Yeah, I also get confused about using "Tilesets" and "Styles" from studio, it would seem that "Styles" are really there to help you create a custom basemap, and "Tilesets" are for layers that you intend to dynamically style when bringing them in as a source/layer in mapbox gl/js. Is that about right?

Comment: No, I wouldn't agree with that. I'd really suggest reading all the docs and examples carefully.